# android how to get organic users (Direct users from Google Play Store) using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I need to get organic users (Users from Google Play Store) using firebase. Here organic users means who search the app on google play store and click install button.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer by hard search around.
Implementing Firebase Analytics --> Events one can get campaign measurement **Referrer** parameters such as: utm_source,utm_medium, utm_term , utm_content and utm_campaign.
For above one can create custom events as well or default events such as 
FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.CAMPAIGN_DETAILS,extras);
futher more FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SOURCE,utm_source, FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SOURCE,utm_medium,FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SOURCE,utm_campaign parameters should be used to send intent's value received by the custom broadcast receiver.
Here :
* extras ---->         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
* utm_source,utm_medium and utm_campaign ---> INSTALL_REFERRER values from intent.

The above mentioned method is without implementation of Deep Linking (FireBase).